# Вывод надписи, если поля в БД пустые

Tags: php, mysql

На странице выводится список студентов из БД MySQL, как сделать так чтобы выводилась это надпись "Вы не добавили ни одного студента!", если ячейки пусты? Вернее, еще нет данных в БД.

Сделал в итоге так:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) < 1) {print "Нет ни одного студента";}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно для этого используют **`mysql_affected_rows()`**

Comment: Разобрался. Ну да, по идее mysql_affected_rows() годен, но только для INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE запросов. А для SELECT запроса используется mysql_num_rows.

Answer (score 1):

Например так 
if (count($students) < 1) print "Нет ни одного студента";